# I need help making my button navigate to a different gameobject or scene in Unity. Can someone help me?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button, navigation

Can someone help me? I have been trying to make my buttons work in Unity! I have watched multiple youtube videos and none of them work for me!

*I want my play button to show a gameobject and hide the current gameobject.

Image of my workspace : -

[image]

I have watched many tutorials, and had many results:

- I am using visual studio code yet scene management is not recognized.
- Even when my settings are set to highlight the button when selected, there is no result.
- I have tried gameobject but its just not working, im not recieving an error there is just no proof my button is actually being pressed!
- I removed my background and pulled the button to the front, to see if it was being covered, but It still had no proof my button is actually being pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of All just make sure you have set the External Tools in Unity Preferences to Visual Studio Code and you have install the Visual Studio Code Package in Unity Package Manager.

I hope you have an UI Managing Script or even not that's not a Problem. In OnClick() make sure you have referenced the GameObject and Selected the SetActive(),

and Click + icon and add another field in that Reference[Drag and Drop] the current button to and Select SetActive() that checkbox present shows the state to be changed into. Please Make Sure you are setting it Correctly.

[image: like this]

I hope this helps.